# WPF or WinForms in Paint Program? (GPU acceleration)

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, gpu

I have made a program like MsPaint in WinForms and I am thinking of moving it into WPF.

I have seen many articles and it is quite clear to me that it's worth doing, when it comes to invalidating controls, which in this case happens very often (ex. line tool).

One of my friend made the same program using Java Swing and we came across interesting thing.
We are having both the same algorithms "Flood Fill" for filling the closed spaces (Bucket tool).

His program makes is much faster. In this algorithm there is just complicated computation on BitMap and there is just **One repaint** in the end.

My question is that it can be caused by **GPU acceleration**, which is present in Java Swing and WinForms doesn't make use of it? In other words can (GPU accelerated) Wpf make operations on Bitmap (that is not displayed) faster than WinForms?

So here's the code Mine 12 sec on complicated BMP 1000x1000:

```
        public override void MyMouseDownSubscriber(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e, System.Drawing.Pen pen)
    {
        // public void floodFill(BufferedImage image, Point node, Color targetColor, Color replacementColor) {
        PictureBox canvas =  (PictureBox)sender;
        Bitmap image = (Bitmap) canvas.Image;
        int width = image.Width;
        int height = image.Height;            
        Color replacementColor = pen.Color;
        Point node = e.Location;
        Color targetColor = image.GetPixel(node.X, node.Y);
        int target = targetColor.ToArgb();
        if (targetColor != replacementColor)
        {
            Queue<Point> queue = new Queue<Point> ();
            bool noMorePixelsLeft = false;
            do
            {
                int x = node.X;
                int y = node.Y;
                while (x > 0 && image.GetPixel(x - 1, y).ToArgb() == target)
                {
                    x--;
                }
                bool spanUp = false;
                bool spanDown = false;
                while (x < width && image.GetPixel(x, y).ToArgb() == target)
                {
                    image.SetPixel(x, y, replacementColor);
                    if (!spanUp && y > 0 && image.GetPixel(x, y - 1).ToArgb() == target)
                    {
                        queue.Enqueue(new Point(x, y - 1));
                        spanUp = true;
                    }
                    else if (spanUp && y > 0 && image.GetPixel(x, y - 1).ToArgb() != target)
                    {
                        spanUp = false;
                    }
                    if (!spanDown && y < height - 1 && image.GetPixel(x, y + 1).ToArgb() == target)
                    {
                        queue.Enqueue(new Point(x, y + 1));
                        spanDown = true;
                    }
                    else if (spanDown && y < height - 1 && image.GetPixel(x, y + 1).ToArgb() != target)
                    {
                        spanDown = false;
                    }
                    x++;
                }
                noMorePixelsLeft = false;
                if (queue.Count > 0)
                {
                    node = queue.Dequeue();
                    noMorePixelsLeft = true;
                }
                else noMorePixelsLeft = false;
            } while (noMorePixelsLeft);
            canvas.Invalidate();
            canvas.Update();
        } 
    }
```

And the one in JavaSwing :0,5 sec on complicated BMP 1000x1000

```
private void floodFill(BufferedImage image, Point startPoint, Color targetColor, Color replacementColor) {
   int width = image.getWidth();
   int height = image.getHeight();
   int target = targetColor.getRGB();
   int replacement = replacementColor.getRGB();

   if (target != replacement) {
     Deque<Point> queue = new LinkedList<>();
     do {
       int x = startPoint.x;
       int y = startPoint.y;
       while (x > 0 && image.getRGB(x - 1, y) == target) x--;
       boolean spanUp = false;
       boolean spanDown = false;
       while (x < width && image.getRGB(x, y) == target) {
         image.setRGB(x, y, replacement);
         if (!spanUp && y > 0 && image.getRGB(x, y - 1) == target) {
           queue.add(new Point(x, y - 1));
           spanUp = true;
         } else if (spanUp && y > 0 && image.getRGB(x, y - 1) != target) spanUp = false;

         if (!spanDown && y < height - 1 && image.getRGB(x, y + 1) == target) {
           queue.add(new Point(x, y + 1));
           spanDown = true;
         } else if (spanDown && y < height - 1 && image.getRGB(x, y + 1) != target) spanDown = false;
         x++;
       }
     } while ((startPoint = queue.pollFirst()) != null);
   }

 }
```

Comment: That's unlikely, none of these class libraries have a dedicated FloodFill() method.  Your friend probably just copied better code.  Not sure why we are supposed to guess at what your code looks like, it doesn't help us help you.

Comment: We don't use dedicated FloodFill() method. We just implemented the same filling algorithm -Smith–Waterman algorithm. Of course there can be some diffrence in our implementation.(diffrent collections etc.) 
I think i could paste only my code, but what i wanted to know was just, if the gpu accelereted technologies (such as WPF,Swing) can make such computatnion faster?

Comment: Generally they can, but I wouldn't bet such a guess in this particular case. As Hans Passant pointed out, there's no dedicated FloodFill(). Thus, it doesn't depend on WPF/Swing/etc., because they don't do it. It is up to you to implement a GPU program to leverage its capabilities, *unless* you call some other GPU-based methods in these frameworks. But what you do, we don't know.

Comment: First of all: don't use image.Get/SetPixel() if you are getting/setting more than just a few pixels. Lock the image bytes into a raw array and perform your manipulations on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answear to my question.

### **The couses of diffrence:**

The difference in the time of executing the algorithm between Java and C# was not coused by qpu acceleration but by the time that methods GetPixel/SetPixel last.
In C# this method last very long.

### Solution

The Bitmap class has a method LockBits that returns just plain data of the colors of the pixels.
The Marshal.Copy allows you to copy the elements to the int[][] matrix and from matrix back to the bitmap.
The implemented methods are here:
http://pastebin.com/SVX3w3tF

Answer (score 0):

For a strict bitmap-based application, I'd stay with Winforms.

WPF is much more targeted for vector and declarative graphics: a program like MSPaint would turn in a hybrid-way approach using a buffer to fill by your own app. That is, take leverage on the GDI+ APIs (the Winforms).

I don't know how to get your app faster using a bitmap-way.